# Condición En LEFT JOIN no Valida

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy realizando una consulta que me taren el valor de **Bonos** y sus id para después hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con el **Personal** que tiene esos bonos y sumarlos pero estos bonos están creados en un rango de fechas la consulta la realizo bien pero al poner los rangos de fechas no quiere aceptarlo, me podrían decir donde tengo el error, les dejo el mensaje de error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1
> ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in
> /home/bqcmjkzk/testingsite1.alteck.net/Bonos_Personal.php:167 Stack
> trace: #0
> /home/bqcmjkzk/testingsite1.alteck.net/Bonos_Personal.php(167):
> mysqli_fetch_assoc(false) #1 {main} thrown in
> /home/bqcmjkzk/testingsite1.alteck.net/Bonos_Personal.php on line 167

Este es la primera consulta que se realiza bien sin el rango de fechas:

````
$sql="SELECT SUM(monto) as monto FROM bonos_asignados a LEFT JOIN Bonos_Creados c ON a.id_bono = c.id where id_usuario='$IDpersonal' ";
$sql.=" AND id_bono NOT IN (SELECT id_bono FROM registro_retiro_bonos WHERE id_afectado='$IDpersonal'";
$sql.=" AND fecha>='$inicio' AND fecha<='$final'+INTERVAL +1 DAY)";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con->query($sql));
$TotalBonosRetirados=$result['monto'];```
````

Después este que es el que necesito y el que debería ser ya que ocupo ese rango de fechas:

```
$sql="SELECT SUM(monto) as monto FROM bonos_asignados a LEFT JOIN Bonos_Creados c ON a.id_bono = c.id where id_usuario='$IDpersonal' AND fecha>='$inicio' AND fecha<='$final'";
$sql.=" AND id_bono NOT IN (SELECT id_bono FROM registro_retiro_bonos WHERE id_afectado='$IDpersonal'";
$sql.=" AND fecha>='$inicio' AND fecha<='$final'+INTERVAL +1 DAY)";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con->query($sql));
$TotalBonosRetirados=$result['monto'];
```

Comment: ¿No debería ser `fecha >= $inicio AND  fecha <= $final`?

Comment: agarra el query resultante y probalo en la DB.. asi podemos ver que error tira la DB...